# Code Format, Structure, consistency

Tags: java

Hello I am a beginner and currently trying to learn java programming. 
The question in the textbook:

Write a program that helps a person decide whether to buy a hybrid car. Your program’s inputs should be:
•The cost of a new car 
•The estimated miles driven per year 
•The estimated gas price •The efficiency in miles per gallon 
•The estimated resale value after 5 years

Compute the total cost of owning the car for five years. (For simplicity, we will not take the cost of financing into account.) Obtain realistic prices for a new and used hybrid and a comparable car from the Web. Run your program twice, using today’s gas price and 15,000 miles per year. Include pseudocode and the program runs with your assignment.

My question: I got the code right, my program runs perfectly. My main concern is how can I present this in a professional manner. How can I structure it professionally, what would I have to do in order to have it published (for example). I am trying to get in the habit of having my codes organized and neatly presented. Any suggestions would help, thanks!

```
public class car
{



public static void main(String[] args)

{

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Car Model: ");
    String carModel = in.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Cost of Car: ");
    int costOfCar = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("The estimated miles driven per year: ");
    int milesDriven = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("The estimated gas price: ");
    int gasPrice = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Efficiency in miles per gallon: ");
    int milesPerGallon = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Estimated resale value after 5 years: ");
    int retailValue = in.nextInt();



    double carEfficiency = (double) gasPrice / milesPerGallon;
    double milesDrivenCost = (double) milesDriven * carEfficiency * 5; //5 years of driving
    double retailValueInFiveYears = retailValue;
    double carUseLoss = costOfCar - retailValueInFiveYears;
    double totalCost = carUseLoss + milesDrivenCost;
    System.out.print(carModel + " will cost you after 5 years: ");
    System.out.format(" %,d%n", Math.round(totalCost));

    }
 }
```

Comment: Follow object orientation.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ will be the right place

Comment: Start by respecting the Java naming conventions, and by indenting the code properly.

Comment: Add some functions, and ya.. OOP, maybe the different vars are member vars

Comment: @Dipak What do you have in mind for OO? Just a service class that holds a bunch of functions that spit out calculated values? Maybe a class for reading input? There doesn't really seem to be any particular entity to represent.

Comment: @jpmc26 First of all a Generic Class, may be Vehicle/Automobiles, and a Service class which calculate efficiency for given instance of  Vehicle/Automobiles object for a given 'Period'

And of-course i will not mix up reading values with in the same class or entity, main function may create instance of Vehicle/Automobiles and invoke a particular service for that, in this case TotalCostService.

Comment: @Dipak I could be missing something, but I don't see the value in a Vehicle/Automobiles class. How does that help readability or maintainability or correctness over a couple of numbers? I can't think of any behavior the V/A or Period class would have. It seems they just wrap a few numbers and a string. I think my biggest piece of advice to the OP is write short functions. They're easier to understand and get right.

Comment: @jpmc26 'Write short functions', me too star it five.
My point about V/A or Period was to, considering the further changes that may come with it. Like adding different kind of Vehicles, or different period or may be weighted periods of time, Using these for different user interfaces.

What I think is, generalizing features to simple and different class, based on real life scenario, has as impotent as what we get from writing short functions to get readability, redundancy, maintainability and correctness over a system.

Answer (score 2):

1. I hope that's not your real indentation.
2. Use Java naming conventions.  In particular, class `car` should be 'Car'.
3. I would have said add a few comments, but variable names are pretty descriptive.
4. Add JavaDoc comments to the class and to the `main` method.
5. Always close resources explicitly.
6. The user could want to enter several of the inputs with decimals.  Use `double`s instead of `int`s.  Scanner will accept numbers with no decimals too.
7. Perhaps you could include the generated JavaDoc HTML output.

Java code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Computes a car's 5-year cost of ownership.
 * Usage:
 *    java Car
 * 
 * @author Mario Rossi
 */
public class Car {

    /**
     * Computes a car's 5-year cost of ownership.
     * 
     * @param args  Not used.  
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Car Model: ");
        String carModel = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Cost of Car: ");
        double costOfCar = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Estimated miles driven per year: ");
        double milesDriven = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Estimated gas price in $ per gallon: ");
        double gasPrice = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Efficiency in miles per gallon: ");
        double milesPerGallon = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Estimated resale value after 5 years: ");
        double retailValueInFiveYears = in.nextDouble();
        in.close();

        double carEfficiency = gasPrice / milesPerGallon;
        double milesDrivenCost = milesDriven * carEfficiency * 5; //5 years of driving
        double carUseLoss = costOfCar - retailValueInFiveYears;
        double totalCost = carUseLoss + milesDrivenCost;
        System.out.print(carModel + " will cost you after 5 years: ");
        System.out.format(" %,.2f%n", totalCost );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to use the Object Oriented approach i.e. follow the rules:

- Abstraction : Identify the entities as classes and their attributes
  and operations.  you have created a class Car but not defined its
  attributes and operations properly so think around it.
- Enacapsulation: Data hiding, make sure you use the proper access
  specifiers for your Class attributes and operations
- Inheritence: Car is quite an abstract thing, so you better define an
  abstract class. And inherit real classes such as Ford Car, Merc Car
  from your base Car class.
- Polymorphism : When you define your Car and its subclasses, you may
  have to override the methods define in your abstract class into your
  child classses.

**Packaging** the software: You can do it in multiple ways:

1. Package it is an executable jar, so a user can simply double click it and run
2. Create an exe file, which internally calls your java code.
3. etc

you may have to write a release note or a small documentation to mention that jre should be installed on the computer, path should be set etc.

hope it helps!

Comment: I think `car` is just an arbitrary name. OP isn't trying to represent a car as an entity, just trying to run some numbers.

Comment: @jpmc26 Ideally Car should be a class with attributes modelNo, cost etc as he has used in his code. As Car is abstract, so it should be an abstract class. And other classes should inherit as i mention in my answer.

Comment: I think we have different opinions on how to write OO code. I've started subscribing to the school of thought that OO is about communication between objects. A "car" class wouldn't have anything to communicate, no services to provide. At most, it'd be a DTO holding the model, cost, and resale values. Rather, you might want some kind of "calculator" class that provides the functionality for calculating values and maybe one to read input. I've been heavily influenced by this: [Why You Don't Get Mocks](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9FOchgTtLM).

Answer (score 0):

as you said you are beginner and started to learn the java, you should always keep the following things in mind,

1. As Java is object oriented and your program is like as c program you must use the OOPs concepts like class, object and all.
2. While writing the program you should use the proper indentation.
3. While giving names for variables, methods use proper naming conventions and don't forget to give comments so that new users can get for what purpose what things you have given.
4. As you learn new thing try to implement these in your programs or in project.
5. Try the packages and try to keep small classes and programs so that you will not get confused in the future as well as other users too.

If you find this answer is useful then don't forget to mark as accepted..